# Update function keeps on giving MethodNotAllowedHttpException in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, view, controller, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

i am **trying to update the values through a form** but i am getting the error over and over again.
[image: error on update]

here is the blade code

```
    <div class="container" >
      <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 50px; padding-left: 25em">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img src="{{$user->photo ? asset($user->photo->file) : 
asset('image/default.png')}}" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; float: 
left; border-radius: 50%; margin-right: 25px">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 ">
                {!! Form::model($user, ['method'=>'PUT' ,'action'=>
['ProfileController@update',$user->id],'files'=>true])!!}
                <div class=form-group style="margin: 50px">
                    <h2>{{$user->name}}'s profile</h2>
                    {!! Form::label('name','Name :') !!}
           {!! Form::text('name', null , ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
           {!! Form::label('email', 'Email :') !!}
           {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
           {!! Form::label('photo_id', 'Profile Picture :') !!}
           {!! Form::file('photo_id', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
           {!! Form::label('password', 'Password:') !!}
         {!! Form::password('password', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}

                </div>
            </div>
     <div class="row" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 50%;">
        {!! Form::submit('Update Profile', ['class'=>'btn btn-info']) !!}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the controller part

```
 public function updateProfile(UserRequest $request, $id)
   {
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        if (trim($request->password)==''){
            $input = $request->except('password');
        }
        else{
            $input = $request->all();
            $input['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);
        }
        if ($request->file('photo_id'== '')){
            $input = $request->except('photo_id');
        }
        elseif ($file = $request->file('photo_id')){
            $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move('image', $name);
            $photo = Photo::create(['file'=>$name]);
            $input['photo_id'] = $photo->id;
        }
        $user->update($input);
    //  Session::flash('edited_profile','The profile has been updated');
   // $input['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);
        return redirect('/');
  // return $request->all();
  }
```

i figured it might be because of the routes not been assigned properly so i made them other than resources [image: routes list]

```
Route::resource('/profile/', 'ProfileController');
Route::get('/profile/{id}', 'ProfileController@editProfile')
   ->name('editProfile');
   Route::post('/profile/{id}', 'ProfileController@updateProfile')
   ->name('updateProfile');
```

when i was trying to get the view via ProfileController@edit route i was getting [image: error on edit view] the error. I made ProfileController@editProfile route and it started giving me the view but update is still not working

Comment: Have you added a csrf token? Also try it with your Route::get and Route::post routes commented out.

Comment: Your code is slightly confused, your routes suggest that you have two update methods, one is called @update() one is called @updateProfile, the first one using the put method and the second one is using post method, you should be able to solve it yourself if you remove the duplicate methods

Comment: tried it befor but didnt worked @UX Labs

Comment: included that too, but it  didn't resolved it @connormcwood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with not updating is that your form is submitting via `PUT` and you declared it's a post call in your routes. So either solution underneath will resolve the issue:

**Solution 1**

update.blade.php

```
{!! Form::model($user, 
     ['method' => 'PUT',
      'action' => [
         'ProfileController@update',$user->id
      ],
      'files' => true
    ])
!!}
```

web.php

```
Route::put('/profile/{id}', 'ProfileController@updateProfile')->name('updateProfile');
```

**Solution 2**

update.blade.php

```
{!! Form::model($user, 
     ['method' => 'POST',
      'action' => [
         'ProfileController@update',$user->id
      ],
      'files' => true
    ])
!!}
```

web.php

```
Route::post('/profile/{id}', 'ProfileController@updateProfile')->name('updateProfile');
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your resource route definition. You've including a trailing slash, and this is messing up the defined routes.

When defining a resource route, the item after the last slash in the definition is the resource, and everything before it is just a route prefix. So, with the definition of `/profile/`, your resource is empty, and your route prefix is "/profile". This is why your routes are not defined correctly and not working as expected.

Remove the trailing slash and your profile resource routing will work:

```
Route::resource('profile', 'ProfileController');
```

You can also get rid of the two extra routes you've defined.